# How to change the label background when using the OutlinedTextBox style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, material-design-in-xaml

I've encountered one problem while working with `TextBox` outlined style. I managed to change the font color in `App.xaml`, but I can't figure out how to change the text background when I click on the `TextBox`. Do you know what to do about it?

[image: TextBox with outlined style in floating state displaying a blue border and a hint on the top left with a grey background and blue text spelling "Enter username".]

```
<TextBox  x:Name="txt_Username" 
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Enter username"
          Background="{x:Null}"
          Height="70"
          Width="300"
          FontFamily="Tolkien"
          BorderThickness="2"
          BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
          Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
          FontSize="22"
          Foreground="#FFEBE2E2" 
          Margin="0,-58,0,221" CaretBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}"
          />
```

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the text or the background of the Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the hint background in both non-floating *and* floating state, use hint assist.

```
materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="Red"
```

Setting different backgrounds for non-floating and floating state is more difficult. Unfortunately, MaterialDesign does *not* expose a property to detect if the hint is currently floating or not. It is only available on the `SmartHint` element *within* the control template of the `TextBox`. Therefore, you cannot simply access it from outside and use a style trigger to change the background color.

If you want a definite solution, you have to copy the default styles (multiple, since the outlined style is based on others) from GitHub [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml) for your version and adapt the `MaterialDesignTextBoxBase`.

- The trigger for the floating style is the [`MultiTrigger` in line 360](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/39a9ca52a445f92f203320b15e6132d7d2f7359a/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L360).
- The condition that determines the internal [floating state is in line 364](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/39a9ca52a445f92f203320b15e6132d7d2f7359a/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml#L364).

  ```
  <Condition SourceName="Hint" Property="IsHintInFloatingPosition" Value="True" />
  ```
- Adapt line 367 and set the brush that you want to apply for the floating state.

  ```
  <Setter Property="wpf:HintAssist.Background" Value="Red" />
  ```

The other derived style down to `MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox` do not have to be adapted, but you need to copy them nevetheless to override them, otherwise they will be based on the original base styles.

---

There is a simple workaround for the moment. The brush in floating state is set to the `MaterialDesignPaper` brush, which is only used in this scenario, so overriding it locally changes the background color, but only if you did not set a background using hint assist. It will take precedence.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt_Username" 
         ...>
   <TextBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignPaper" Color="Red"/>
   </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Please be aware that the implementation might change and break this workaround in the future.

[image: Hint in non-floating state without background on the left and in floating state with red background on the right.]